# ArcMap CSV Export

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, postgresql, cursor, arcgis-10.5

I am working on a export from ArcMap 10.5 with a PostgreSQL databse in Arc Server.

I have polygons with addresses within it. 
I am trying to create a CSV Export, for the addresses within that polygon. That all is working fine.

But what I am not getting correct is that I want two columns (WE and GE) to be added in the export into one colomn. It is staying blank.

So now it is:
0"tzipcode", 1"Stadt", 2"Straße", 3"Nr", 4"Zusatz", 5"WE", 6"GE", 7"Anzahl", 8"SHAPE@X", 9"SHAPE@Y"

So I am trying to make a the 5th column in the CSV a we_ge (we+ge). 
But it's staying blank.

Can somebody give me a tip... because I am stuck on this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
import os
import csv

def fcl_to_csv(fcl, csv_path):
  with open(csv_path, "w", newline="\n", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    # TODO define UTF-8
    # TODO WE -> WE plus GE
    fields = [u"tzipcode", u"Stadt", u"Straße", u"Nr", u"Zusatz", u"WE", u"GE", u"Anzahl", u"SHAPE@X", u"SHAPE@Y"]
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcl, fields) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        if row[5] is None or row[6] is None:
          we_ge = None
        else:
          we_ge = row[5] + row[6]
        csv_row = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], we_ge, row[7], row[8], row[9]]
        csv_writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

Comment: What does `WE` and `GE` contain?

Comment: the WE and GE contain numbers

Comment: Ah, I see what happend.The column WE or GE can be empty <Null>. So if here WE or GE is <null> the result is now also blank. How do I handle that <null> value

Comment: Have you tried printing the value in those two columns? `print row[5]` - to determine what's happening

Comment: So if `WE` is empty then return `GE` only?

Comment: So, WE + GE must be we_ge. In that case <null> + 5 must be 5 OR 5 + <null> must be 5 OR 5 + 5 must be 10.

Comment: so i think the error must be in here: if row[5] is None or row[6] is None:
          we_ge = None     but how to let it hanle the <null>

Comment: we_ge = None or 0? (if both are None)

Comment: if both are None and/or 0 ---> it should be 0

Comment: Now to confirm, you want to add the numbers together - `we = 3` and `ge = 4` produces `we_ge = 7`, and not `we_ge = 34`?

Comment: Are `we` and `ge` integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute a `0` for the `None` in separate variables, then calculate the `we_ge`:

```
for row in cursor:
    we = row[5]
    ge = row[6]
    if we is None:
        we = 0
    if ge is None:
        ge = 0
    we_ge = we + ge
    csv_row = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], we_ge, row[7], row[8], row[9]]
```

If the `row[5]` and `row[6]` values are integers (no decimals) then the following may work:

```
for row in cursor:
    we = int(row[5] or 0)
    ge = int(row[6] or 0)
    we_ge = we + ge
    csv_row = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], we_ge, row[7], row[8], row[9]]
```